# Custom slot label in timeline view depending on date

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

Is it possible to add custom text to slot period in fullcalendar ? 
I need to add custom text depending on date
Instead of January, February, March I need 'Stage 1', April, May, June - 'Stage 2' and so on
http://prntscr.com/j581pn

Comment: can you share your work? You are referring to this? https://fullcalendar.io/docs/monthNames

Answer (score 1):

Add a custom array for the calendar. By default the array will come up like

```
monthNames:['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July','August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
```

Try replacing this array with

```
monthNames:['Stage 1', 'Stage 1', 'Stage 1', 'Stage 2', 'Stage 2', 'Stage 2', 'Stage 3','Stage 3', 'Stage 3', 'Stage 4', 'Stage 4', 'Stage 4']
```

Refer the following link in the documentation
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/monthNames

Comment: That works for now, but if i should change Stages for days ? for example stage 1 - 10 days, stage 2 - 100 days, stage 3 - 40 days etc

Comment: you want to highlight each stage days? or you want to change the dates in the usual calender

Comment: no, i just need to make custom labels depending on duration. Right now i change only month, but there in no way out. Like i mentioned above, i need custom stages depending on days.

Comment: @DimkaGanin that wasn't actually what you asked for, though. Lakindu has answered the question you posed, correctly. If your requirement was different, you should have made that clear to begin with.

Comment: @ADyson, actually my question is correct. I said, depending on date. Not, months

Comment: @DimkaGanin perhaps, but it wasn't very clear in that case. The example was using months. If there was more variance than that, you should have specified. If the example uses months, and the text is not more specific, then people are entitled to think that's what you want.